# Spinor expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, spinors, approximations

does anyone know how you get this expansion when expanding terms of 4-momentum to linear order, type of expansion is it?

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of Taylor or MacLaurin expansion?

Comment: Hi yes but I have not much experience using it, thought you had to expand about a point and take derivatives of the function at that point so not sure where the m and square root m comes from. Whenever I come across Taylor expansion I know I'm in trouble :D

Answer (score 3):

I believe that $p\cdot\sigma=p^{\mu}\sigma_{\mu}=E-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$. So,
$$\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}=\sqrt{E-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}=\sqrt{m-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}=\sqrt{m}\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}{m}}$$
Now using $\sqrt{1+x}=1+x/2+O(x^2)$
$$\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\approx\sqrt{m}\big(1-\frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}{2m}\big)$$
Similarly, do the expansion for $\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma}}$.

Comment: Please don't give full answers to homework-type problems.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual underlying problem is here, but I kind of doubt that this is answering it. This seems more like an answer to the conceptual question. (Though we can't tell for sure without clarification from the question asker)

Comment: you have answered it kind of, thanks, i was confused why used m instead of E, because we assume p small?

Comment: No because $E=mc^2$ and I believe the text took $c=1$, which is standard to use in QFT.

Comment: Okay thanks I was thinking relativistic E